# Having issues trying to prompt parameter fields in the aws cloudformation CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-cli

I have a functional stack that works on the console but has issues when I try to run it in the CLI. This is what happens:

```
[user@lsikala1 ~]$ aws cloudformation create-stack --stack-name G2Devopsproject --template-body https://s3.amazonaws.com/g2internship2018/G2InternshipDevopsbuild.json 
An error occurred (ValidationError) when calling the CreateStack operation: Parameters: [KeyName, Subnets, DBPassword, VpcId, DBUser] must have values
```

Answer (score 0):

The AWS CLI won't prompt you for parameters when creating CloudFormation stacks. Instead you'll have to provide them using the `--parameters` parameter. From the [reference of the `create-stack`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudformation/create-stack.html) command:

> `--parameters` (list)
>
> A list of Parameter structures that specify input parameters for the
>   stack. […]

Of course you only have to specify parameter values without a default in your CloudFormation template.

Comment: So in order to set key value pair I need to write like: (for KeyName)  ParameterKey=KeyName, ParameterValue=MYEC2KeyPair ?

Comment: After I did that this is want I got [user@lsikala1 ~]$ aws cloudformation create-stack --parameters ParameterKey=KeyName ParameterValue=MyEC2KeyPair ParameterKey=Subnets ParameterValue=subnet-1181652e ParameterKey=DBPassword ParameterValue=password ParameterKey=VpcI
d ParameterValue=vpc-74683b0d ParameterKey=DBUser ParameterValue=admin --stack-name G2Devopsproject --template-body https://s3.amazonaws.com/g2internship2018/G2InternshipDevopsbuild.json 
An error occurred (ValidationError) when calling the CreateStack operation: ParameterValue for ParameterKey KeyName is required

Comment: So I passed the parameters through a separate json file but now I'm having a issue passing in an array for the multiple subnets. I keep getting the same error as before.